# jquery sortable stoppropagation for sub items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

in this example

https://jsfiddle.net/mkash0bn/

if you move children menu( sub menu ) will get alert message twice

on update event
if you add stopPropagation(),preventDefault

not fix the issue
any help appricated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css">




  <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
        .sortable {

    }
    .group-caption {
        background: #D3CAAF;
        width: 400px;
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    }
    .group-items {
      min-height: 40px;
    }
    .group-item {
        background: #5E5E5E;
        width: 300px;
        height: 30px;
        display: block;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 5px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .move {
        background: #ff0000;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        float: right;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-family: Arial;
        cursor: move;
    }
    .item-placeholder {
        background: #ccc;
        width: 300px;
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;
        border-style: dashed;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-color: #000;
    }
    .movable-placeholder {
        background: #ccc;
        width: 400px;
        height: 100px;
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;
        border-style: dashed;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-color: #000;
    }
    


  </style>

  <script id="insert"></script>

    <script src="fiddle.jshell.net_files/stringify.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
      const customConsole = (w) => {
        const pushToConsole = (payload, type) => {
          w.parent.postMessage({
            console: {
              payload: stringify(payload),
              type:    type
            }
          }, "*")
        }

        w.onerror = (message, url, line, column) => {
          // the line needs to correspond with the editor panel
          // unfortunately this number needs to be altered every time this view is changed
          line = line - 70
          if (line < 0){
            pushToConsole(message, "error")
          } else {
            pushToConsole(`[${line}:${column}] ${message}`, "error")
          }
        }

        let console = (function(systemConsole){
          return {
            log: function(){
              let args = Array.from(arguments)
              pushToConsole(args, "log")
              systemConsole.log.apply(this, args)
            },
            info: function(){
              let args = Array.from(arguments)
              pushToConsole(args, "info")
              systemConsole.info.apply(this, args)
            },
            warn: function(){
              let args = Array.from(arguments)
              pushToConsole(args, "warn")
              systemConsole.warn.apply(this, args)
            },
            error: function(){
              let args = Array.from(arguments)
              pushToConsole(args, "error")
              systemConsole.error.apply(this, args)
            },
            system: function(arg){
              pushToConsole(arg, "system")
            },
            clear: function(){
              systemConsole.clear.apply(this, {})
            },
            time: function(){
              let args = Array.from(arguments)
              systemConsole.time.apply(this, args)
            },
            assert: function(assertion, label){
              if (!assertion){
                pushToConsole(label, "log")
              }

              let args = Array.from(arguments)
              systemConsole.assert.apply(this, args)
            }
          }
        }(window.console))

        window.console = { ...window.console, ...console }

        console.system("Running fiddle")
      }

      if (window.parent){
        customConsole(window)
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="cursor: auto;">
    <div class="sortable ui-sortable">
  
  <div class="group-caption">
    <h4>PARENT #1</h4>
    <div class="move">+</div>
    <div class="group-items ui-sortable">
      <div class="group-item">CHILD #1<div class="move">+</div></div>
      <div class="group-item" style="">CHILD #3<div class="move">+</div></div><div class="group-item">CHILD #2<div class="move">+</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="group-caption">
    <h4>PARENT #2</h4>
    <div class="move">+</div>
    <div class="group-items ui-sortable">
      
      <div class="group-item">CHILD #4<div class="move">+</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="group-caption">
    <h4>PARENT #3</h4>
    <div>
    <div class="move">+</div>
    <div class="group-items ui-sortable">
      <div class="group-item">CHILD #5<div class="move">+</div></div>
      <div class="group-item">CHILD #6<div class="move">+</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
    
    // Sort the parents
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        containment: "parent",
        items: "> div",
        handle: ".move",
        tolerance: "pointer",
        cursor: "move",
        opacity: 0.7,
        revert: 300,
        delay: 150,
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        placeholder: "movable-placeholder",
        start: function(e, ui) {
            ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.outerHeight());
        }
    });
    
    // Sort the children
    $(".group-items").sortable({
        containment: "document",
        items: ".group-item",
        placeholder: "item-placeholder",
        connectWith: '.group-items',update: function(event, ui) {
    alert('ok');
}
    });
    
})



</script>


</div></body></html>
```

if you move children menu( sub menu ) will get alert message twice

on update event if you add stopPropagation(),preventDefault

not fix the issue any help appricated

Answer (score 0):

When dragging a submenu item from one menu to another, the `update` event is firing from both the source and destination menus. The fix is to ignore one of the events. You can differentiate between the two `update` events by inspecting `ui.sender` as in the example below. It will contain the source menu if it was moved from one menu to another.

```
// Sort the children
$(".group-items").sortable({
    containment: "document",
    items: ".group-item",
    placeholder: "item-placeholder",
    connectWith: '.group-items',
    update: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.sender !== null) {
        alert('The event from the source menu');
      } else {
        alert('The event from the destination menu');
      }
    }
});
```